# How to 2 strings with 2 different encodings

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I've an html page with JavaScript. Inside it I load another JavaScript with the tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/../myfile.js" ></script>
```

Furthermore my html page is encoded with the following tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Then, inside a function I get a string defined in "myfile.js" and want to compare it to a string coming from my main page. I tried indexOf, ==, search, match... but the assertion will always be false. I alerted my strings and they were showed as equal (case sensitive).

Anybody has an idea of why my test doesn't work?

Edit : my code looks like the following.

```
window.lang= new myobject(); // this object is defined in myfile.js
var mystring1 = window.lang.attr1['mykey'];
var mystring2 = $("#mydivid").html();
alert(mystring1+":"+mystring2); // this shows 2 equal strings
/* Here I wanted to test if the 2 strings are equals and tried "==", mystring1.indexOf(mystring2), match, search, ... */
```

And in file.js :

```
myobject.prototype.attr1 = {
 'mykey': 'mystring1value'
}
```

Comment: I don't know if there is a link, but one of my strings comes from a jquery command $(...).html().

Comment: Is your script's charset really supposed to be `uft-8` instead of `utf-8`?

Comment: Is “uft-8” a typo in the question or in the actual code? What are the two different encodings? Please provide more info; probably a URL is needed (how else could we see HTTP headers?).

Comment: It is a typo in the question of course, sorry. Theorically everything should be in utf-8, but since Javascript uses Unicode as default I wonder if a string defined in the code is not a Unicode one. The file "myfile.js" is added the static way, there is no http request after page loading.

Answer (score 2):

You need `"utf-8"` ,not `"uft-8"`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/../myfile.js" ></script>
```

Comment: It's a typo in the question, sorry.

Comment: @Ricola3D Can provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), that we could play with it.

Comment: @Ricola3D Try to change `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` to `<meta charset=utf-8 />` .

Comment: I tried your last advice and it did no change. About the jsFiddle I'd like but how can I had local ressources files to a jsFiddle ? It only accepts URLs

Comment: @Ricola3D put the contents of your local resource inside of some public resource, and link it.

Comment: Well after more tests it seems that it is my string from the jquery command that is not equal to the value I expected. It seems a jquery plugin adds some "\n" at the end...

Answer (score 1):

Sample1.html
        
        
        
         New Document

```
    </HEAD>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Sample2.js" ></script>

    <script>
    function compare(){
    j="test";
    alert(i==j);
    }
    </script>

    <BODY onload="compare();">

    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Sample2.js

```
var i="test";
```

**Please try this its works fine for me**

Comment: Yes this works, but it doesn't help me to understand what doesn't work in my case and I cannot change my source file. And since I've an alert that shows me the 2 same strings and then an alert telling me "==" gives false I don't think it is a typo in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly the issue came from a jquery plugin (jsTree) that added some "\n" or "\r" at the end of my strings. Sorry for disturbance and thanks for help !

Cheers,

Ricola3D